# Excel Jet Access, Left Join OR/AND

Tags: excel, ms-access, jet

I have this query for jet access syntax. I query excel sheets internally.

```
select 
cdbl(fs.[Market Value]) as Value
from [database$] as data 
left join [AS$] as fs on data.[FIELD1]=fs.[field1]
```

I have tried things such as `OR data.[FIELD2]=fs.[field2]` but can't get them to work.

How can I add an `OR` for feild2? How can I add an `ADD` for field3?

The logic would be, left join field 1 `OR` field2, `AND` field3.
If none of these, left join field4 `AND` field3,
if none of these return 0/null.

Comment: This sounds as if your data isn't stored correctly.  Multiple fields shouldn't hold the same intrinsic values. Your user name would suggest you have a table like a spreadsheet, which isn't normalised.

Comment: Yes, it is internal queries within my spreadsheets. Sorry should have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your `ON` clause with parameters if you're doing anything but a simple comparison:

```
select 
cdbl(fs.[Market Value]) as Value
from [database$] as data 
left join [AFS$] as fs on (data.[FIELD1]=fs.[field1] OR data.[FIELD2]=fs.[field2])
```

Note that if your only intention is to check if certain data exists, I recommend using an `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Weirdly `OR` seems to crash my excel sheet, but `and` works fine. do you know how to get around this? Can we do `OR` in another way?

Comment: Not with this little info. Hard crashes are very uncommon, they usually indicate something weird is happening. You can try providing an [mcve] with sample data

Comment: I got a question, so say I do something like `(data.[FIELD1]=fs.[field1] and data.[FIELD3]=fs.[field3])` . How do I add another case to this? Like if the first left join doesnt work then I want to left join on field4 and field3 ?